# Python model for correcting the input data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to build a model by taking historic data of a list of fixed length having text of fixed values for each index.

Example: [ABC,BCD,CDE,DEF,EFG]

The model should correct the input new list if there is some invalid value and return the most appropriate value for that column.

Example: if the input is:

[ABC,BCD,CDZ,DEF,EFG]

it should return

[ABC,BCD,CDE,DEF,EFG].

I am struck with this.Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'appropriate value for that column' is it the value in the original list at the same index ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for / ?

```
a = ['ABC','BCD','CDE','DEF','EFG']
b = ['ABC','BCD','CDZ','DEF','EFG']
c = []
for idx, b_ in enumerate(b):
    if b_ not in a :
            c.append(a[idx])
    else:
            c.append(b_)

print(c)

>>> ['ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE', 'DEF', 'EFG']
```

Comment: Yes but there would be multiple values for index 2 in the historic data based on which I would need the closest result based on other indices inputs as well.